# how to change image colors for highlights in android?

Tags: android

I have an image for my app, I need to change every wall color in the imageview. Like this image:

http://www.smple.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/contemporary-living-room-ideas-inspired-design-4-on-living-design-ideas.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grab the pixel RGB value at certain points in your imageView Bitmap. Then from there you can SetPixel, and account for alpha and then flip the pixels in which you want to alter the value.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;
        opt.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap ico = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.colored_wall_pic, opt);

        int color = 15132390 & 0x00FFFFFF; //15132390 is like whiteish gray
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int alpha = ico.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFF000000;
                if (alpha != 0) {
                    ico.setPixel(x, y, color | alpha);
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(ico.getWidth(), ico.getHeight(), ico.getConfig());

        // overlay transparent mutable Bitmap on transparent background
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(icon);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ico, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: width and height of your image. You can just to ico.getWidth() and ico.getHeight() as the values.

Comment: i am sorry can you help me , because i tried but no result , can you help me ??

Comment: Tell us what you've tried, and what error are you getting.

Comment: When you give me solution i can't understand whats is int color <>& 0x00FFFFFF

Comment: Second thing i want to change background every wall for different color,  i sow app like that,  you want to see him??

Comment: that needs to be your int value for color. Go to http://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html to figure out what int value your color is. You want to find something similar so you can "paint" the wall color.

Comment: Can you see this app please https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.aljazeera.idecor

Comment: if you have transparency at the wall color at given x,y it'll go through the entire image and paint where those transparent pixels are located at.

Comment: I am sorry but i am new in the programing with custom image view if you can help me help me...

Comment: You need each of those images with transparency or a solid definitive color so you can paint over it. Essentially what you are doing is examining every pixel on your screen and replacing the pixel value of it with a color of your choice. In the sample I've given you it'll paint a whiteish grayish colour.

Comment: int alpha in my sample is alpha white, you can set it to anything you want, blue, green, red, whatever your image you provided's wall color is. Keep in mind it accounts for a little discrepancy, so it doesn't have to be too close.

Comment: Can i add you on Facebook