# change color of image png for multiple pixel in android?

Tags: android

I have an image for my app, I need to change every wall color in the imageview wall color like living room ... like this image

[how to change image colors for highlights in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344591/how-to-change-image-colors-for-highlights-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grab the pixel RGB value at certain points in your imageView Bitmap. Then from there you can SetPixel, and account for alpha and then flip the pixels in which you want to alter the value.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;
        opt.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap ico = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.colored_wall_pic, opt);

        int color = 15132390 & 0x00FFFFFF; //15132390 is like whiteish gray
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int alpha = ico.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFF000000;
                if (alpha != 0) {
                    ico.setPixel(x, y, color | alpha);
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(ico.getWidth(), ico.getHeight(), ico.getConfig());

        // overlay transparent mutable Bitmap on transparent background
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(icon);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ico, 0, 0, null);
```